# Understanding making multiple GET requests using same connection with aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming, aiohttp

`aiohttp.TCPConnector()` has a `limit` parameter to set the number of simultaneous connections. If I have to make 200 requests to the same site to download different bytes of the same file, then if I create two sessions as below:

```
async def test():
    tcp_connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=100)
    session1 = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector = tcp_connector)
    session2 = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector = tcp_connector)
    url_list = []       #Assume 200 urls to the same site with different range of bytes specified for bytes header
    session = session1
    for i in range(len(url_list)):
        if i%100 == 0:
           session = session2
        async with session.get(url_list[i]) as res:
            await ....
```

Does this mean I am making 2 connections to the site and 100 requests per connection? Because in the aiohttp documentation it says a session reuses the same connection, meaning it avoids TCP 3-way handshake for every request made using `session.get()` after initializing the session at the start. But the limit parameter is documented as:

> limit (int) – total number simultaneous connections. If limit is None the connector has no limit (default: 100).

OR

Does it mean I am making 200 connections to the site?